# mgwt:ScrollPanel jump back to top

Tags: cordova, gwt, mgwt

I'm using a ScrollPanel (mgwt) with a HTMLPanel inside to display a long list of message but when I try to swype down (scroll down), the content scroll but jump back to the top when I let it go.

```
<mgwt:ScrollPanel ui:field="scrollPanel">
    <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="htmlPanel" styleName='{appearance.style.css.popupDynamicContent}'>
        <g:FlowPanel styleName='{appearance.style.css.conseiller}'/>
        <g:Label text="{appearance.messages.popupTitle}"  styleName='{appearance.style.css.popupTitle}'/>

        <nc:MessagesWidget ui:field="nc:MessagesWidget"/>

    </g:HTMLPanel>
</mgwt:ScrollPanel>
```

If I use a gwt ScrollPanel I can scroll through my content fine but I don't have "mobile phone feel" with the bouncing animations, etc...

Does anyone have an idea or a fix for this issue ?

EDIT : The application run in a phonegap container on an android device, but I also have the issue in a browser (firefox) or an other phone.

Answer (score 0):

When did you refresh the scrollPanel? this things occurs when scrollPanel(SP) haven't been refresh after adding content.

Other possibility. I having same trouble with pullPanel and SP which is using in the pullpanel. SP use the wrapper elements to know how many pixel could be scrolling. Check that the wrapper don't have the same height than your scrollPanel. I fixe my probleme by fixing the height value of my wrapper.